# Uploading file to database from input

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am learning Laravel and got stuck with one issue. I have created form with validation and all goes to database. Except my `image_url` with `type="file"`

```
  <form method="POST" action="{{route('photos.store')}}" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<div class="">
   @component('components.back', ['url' => route('photos.index')])
   @endcomponent
   <hr>
</div>
<div class="form-all">
  <ul class="form-section page-section">
    <li class="form-line" data-type="control_image" id="id_1">
      <div id="cid_1" class="form-input-wide">
        <div style="text-align:center;">
          <img alt="" class="form-image" style="border:0px;" src="" height="42px" width="42px" data-component="image">
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="form-line" data-type="control_text" id="id_12">
      <div id="cid_12" class="form-input-wide">
        <div id="text_12" class="form-html" data-component="text">
          <p><span style="color:#363636;font-size:xx-large;">Įkelti nuotrauką</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="form-group{{ $errors->has('title')?' has-error' : ''}}" id="id_7">
      <label class="form-label form-label-top" id="label_7" for="title">Pavadinimas</label>
      <div id="cid_7" class="form-input-wide">
        <input id="title" type="text" name="title" value="{{ old('title') }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Pavadinimas">
        @if ($errors->has('title'))
        <span class="help-block">
          <strong>
          {{ $errors->first('title')}}
          </strong>
        </span>
        @endif  </div>
    </li>

    <li class="form-group{{ $errors->has('description')?
      ' has-error' : ''}}">
      <label class="form-label form-label-top" id="label_5" for="description">Aprašymas</label>
      <div id="cid_5" class="form-input-wide">
        <input id="description" type="text" name="description" value="{{ old('description') }}" class="form-control" placeholder = "Aprašymas">
        @if ($errors->has('description'))
        <span class="help-block">
          <strong>
          {{ $errors->first('description')}}
          </strong>
        </span>
        @endif
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="form-group {{ $errors->has('image_url')?
      ' has-error' : ''}}">
      <label class="form-label form-label-top" id="label_11" for="image_url">Nuotrauka</label>
      <div id="cid_11" class="form-input-wide">

        <input id="image_url" type="file" name="image_url" value="{{ old('image_url') }}" class="form-control">

        @if ($errors->has('image_url'))
        <span class="help-block">
          <strong>
          {{ $errors->first('image_url')}}
          </strong>
        </span>
        @endif
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="form-group {{ $errors->has('category_id') ? 'has-error': ''}}">
      <label class="form-label form-label-top" id="label_11">Kategorija</label>
      @if(isset($photo))
      <select name="category_id" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Pasirinkti kategoriją</option>
        @foreach($categories as $category)
          <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->title}}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
      @else
      <select name="category_id" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Pasirinkti kategoriją</option>
        @foreach($categories as $category)
          <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->title}}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
      @endif

      @if($errors->has('category_id'))
      <span class="help-block">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('category_id')}}</strong>
      </span>
      @endif

    </li>

    <li class="form-line" data-type="control_button" id="id_2">
      <div id="cid_2" class="form-input-wide">
        <div style="text-align:center;" class="form-buttons-wrapper">
          <button id="input_2" type="submit" class="form-submit-button" data-component="button">
            Patvirtinti
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

and my Controller looks like this:

```
public function create()
{
  $categories = Category::all();
  return view('photo.create', compact('photo','categories'));
}
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
   'title' => 'required|min:3',
   'image_url'=> 'required',
   'category_id' => 'required',
    ]);

     $photo = new Photo;


     $photo->title = $request->input('title');
     $photo->image_url = $request->input('image_url');
     $photo->description = $request->input('description');
     $photo->category_id = $request->input('category_id');
     $photo->save();

     $request->session()->flash('create', $request->title. "Sekmingai sukurta");
     $path = $request->image_url->store('images');
     return redirect()->route('photos.index');

}
```

and seeder:

```
public function __construct( Photo $photo, Category $category) {
$this->photo = $photo;
$this->category = $category;
}

public function run()
{
  $categories_ids = $this->category->pluck('id');

      DB::table('photos')->insert(
        [
          'title' => '',
          'image_url' => '',
          'description' => '',
          'category_id' => $categories_ids->random()
        ]);

}
```

I understand that I should put some if into Controller telling "If its not text, but file- accept file". But I am not able to find answer online.
Thank you for your advises in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get image name from `$fileName = $request->image_url->store('images');`
and note `$fileName` wil return folder name also `images/2Q3J1gU3j8NkMgt5HtGurSDtu5BIbeATNZb13Ih3.jpeg`

```
$photo = new Photo;
      if ($request->hasFile('image_url')) {


               $fileName = $request->image_url->store('images');
               $photo->image_url =  $fileName;
            }

         $photo->title = $request->input('title');

         $photo->description = $request->input('description');
         $photo->category_id = $request->input('category_id');
         $photo->save();

         $request->session()->flash('create', $request->title. "Sekmingai sukurta");

         return redirect()->route('photos.index');
```

Comment: It truly works. Thank you. I see it was added into my database and into images folder. But it photo doesn't show up on my form blade.

Comment: for that you need to use url of photo and if you want to show there only hen you have to use jquery .if my answer is helpful please mark answer as accepted